# Rust - ParseIntError { kind: PosOverflow }

Tags: rust

Есть код который проверяет является ли число палиндромом. Но возникли проблемы с unwrap() - `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: PosOverflow }

```
let x = 1234567899;
println!("{}",x.to_string().trim().chars().rev().collect::<String>().parse::<i32>().unwrap() == x);
```

Comment: Во-первых, число 9987654321 не влезает в тип i32. Во-вторых, раз уж вы всё равно преобразуете в строку, то можно же сравнивать тупо строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если явно написать достаточно большой литерал числа, компилятор [предупредит ошибкой](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3e491b2b544c1e527fa2f5cc2351a5d2) еще на первой строке:

```
error: literal out of range for `i32`
 --> src/main.rs:4:13
  |
4 |     let x = 9987654321;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the literal `9987654321` does not fit into the type `i32` whose range is `-2147483648..=2147483647`
  = help: consider using the type `i64` instead
```

В Rust есть [несколько целочисленных типов](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-types). По умолчанию, если не указано иное, для целочисленных литералов используется `i32`. Он, как видно из текста ошибки, ограничен по размеру. Для числа `9987654321` [потребуется](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e5716a25fee5de1be9e7249162de778) тип `i64`, неотрицательный `u64` или их более ёмкие собратья.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 1234567899;
    println!("{}", x.to_string().chars().rev().collect::<String>().parse::<i64>().unwrap() == x);
}
```